# PostgresSQL Order by in mixed way

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by

I have a table:

Table - user

```
user_id     name            country         role        function
1           abc1            US              Developer   IT
2           abc3            US              Developer   IT
3           abc4            US              Developer   IT
4           abc6            US              Developer   IT
5           abc8            US              Developer   IT
6           abc9            US              Developer   IT
7           abc5            Canada          Developer   IT
8           abc2            Canada          Accountant  Finance
9           abc7            US              Accountant  Finance
10          abc10           Canada          Developer   IT
11          abc11           Canada          Accountant  Finance
12          abc12           US              Accountant  Finance
```

How can I order the above table so that I get record of unique combination of `country`, `role` and `function`.

So, the output would be like:

```
user_id     name            country         role        function
1           abc1            US              Developer   IT
7           abc5            Canada          Developer   IT
9           abc7            US              Accountant  Finance
8           abc2            Canada          Accountant  Finance
2           abc3            US              Developer   IT
10          abc10           Canada          Developer   IT
12          abc12           US              Accountant  Finance
11          abc11           Canada          Accountant  Finance
3           abc4            US              Developer   IT
4           abc6            US              Developer   IT
5           abc8            US              Developer   IT
6           abc9            US              Developer   IT
```

The above results using the following logic:

- Find the distinct combination of `country`, `role` and `function`
- Take the first record of the FIRST distinct combination. For ex. Row 1 has country = US, role = Developer, function = IT
- Take the first record of the Second distinct combination. For ex. Row 2 has country = Canada, role = Developer, function = IT
- Take the first record of the THIRD distinct combination. For ex. Row 3 has country = US, role = Accountant, function = Finance
- Take the first record of the FOURTH distinct combination. For ex. Row 4 has country = Canada, role = Accountant, function = Finance

Now, the unique distinct combinations are not there, so the next record would be from the FIRST distinct combination.

Is there a way to achieve this in PostgresSQL?

Comment: I don't follow. How do you order combinations (since you speak of the *first*, *second* etc. combination)? How do you order rows within one combination?

Comment: First combination is - country = US, role = Developer, function = IT. Second combination is country = Canada, role = Developer, function = IT.

Comment: I basically want the records to be ordered so we show records of the first combination, then next record is of the second combination, then of third, then fourth. If there are no more combinations left, get the record of first combination.

Comment: You still have not explain what you mean by "first".

Comment: Find the distinct values of (country, role, function). Then the first distinct value is the "first". Hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
SELECT t.user_id, t.name, t.country, t.role, t.function
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY country, role, function ORDER BY user_id) as rn
  FROM "user"
) t
ORDER BY rn, user_id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sDH2cdDYhZqF4LCcegcEpz/1).
Results:

```
| user_id | name  | country | role       | function |
| ------- | ----- | ------- | ---------- | -------- |
| 1       | abc1  | US      | Developer  | IT       |
| 7       | abc5  | Canada  | Developer  | IT       |
| 8       | abc2  | Canada  | Accountant | Finance  |
| 9       | abc7  | US      | Accountant | Finance  |
| 2       | abc3  | US      | Developer  | IT       |
| 10      | abc10 | Canada  | Developer  | IT       |
| 11      | abc11 | Canada  | Accountant | Finance  |
| 12      | abc12 | US      | Accountant | Finance  |
| 3       | abc4  | US      | Developer  | IT       |
| 4       | abc6  | US      | Developer  | IT       |
| 5       | abc8  | US      | Developer  | IT       |
| 6       | abc9  | US      | Developer  | IT       |
```

In your expected results the rows with `user_id`s 8,9 and 11,12 are in reverse order but you did not explain why.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```sql
WITH data AS (
  SELECT row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY country, role, function) as rownum, *
  FROM user
)
SELECT *
FROM data
ORDER BY rownum
```

```
rownum  user_id name  country role       function
1       11      abc11 Canada  Accountant Finance
1       7       abc5  Canada  Developer  IT
1       12      abc12 US      Accountant Finance
1       5       abc8  US      Developer  IT
2       8       abc2  Canada  Accountant Finance
2       9       abc7  US      Accountant Finance
2       10      abc10 Canada  Developer  IT
2       4       abc6  US      Developer  IT
3       1       abc1  US      Developer  IT
4       3       abc4  US      Developer  IT
5       2       abc3  US      Developer  IT
6       6       abc9  US      Developer  IT
```

Comment: The output does not seem to be right. I have more records, but the output does not show it. Like abc10, abc11, abc12. Would that be considered too?